# Nested while loop for getting db data. Timing out at random times because of the PHP. Any way to make this more efficient?

Tags: php, optimization, mysql

So today I jumbled together a script that would get data from a database, from different tables and such.  I had wanted to just use simple ifs without the whiles, but I couldn't make it possible. The code I posted is useable but randomly times out when testing, and i'm afraid of how it would perform under stress.  Is there any way to improve this code to stop the timing out?

```
<?php
    $getConference = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT confName, tableName FROM conferences WHERE enabled='1' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $catConference = mysql_query($getConference);
    while($conference = mysql_fetch_array($catConference)) {
        echo "<h2 class=\"expand\">".$conference['confName']."</h2>
                <ul class=\"collapse\">";
        $getExistingEvent = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT event FROM " . $conference['tableName']);
        $catExistingEvent = mysql_query($getExistingEvent);
        while($existingevent = mysql_fetch_array($catExistingEvent)) {
            $getCat = sprintf("SELECT * FROM event WHERE id='".$existingevent['event']."'");
            $catResult = mysql_query($getCat);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($catResult)) {
                $getWinner = sprintf("SELECT place, name, event FROM 2012rlc WHERE event='".$row['id']."' ORDER BY place");
                $catWinner = mysql_query($getWinner);
                echo "
                    <li>
                        <h2 class=\"expand\">".$row['eventName']."</h2>
                        <ul class=\"collapse\">
                    ";

                while($winner = mysql_fetch_array($catWinner)) {
                    echo "<li>".$winner['place']. " ".$winner['name']."</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($catResult);
    mysql_free_result($catWinner);
    mysql_free_result($catExistingEvent);
    mysql_free_result($catConference);
?>
```

Some have asked for the database schema, which I have included below:

```
CREATE TABLE `2012rlc` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `place` varchar(4) default '',
    `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `event` int(5) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `conferences` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `confName` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `tableName` varchar(50) default NULL,
    `enabled` tinyint(1) default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `eventName` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `teamEvent` tinyint(1) default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Output to EXPLAIN MySQL command:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  conferences ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: What is the difference between `conferences.confName` and `2012rlc.name`? Is the schema in [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does you tables have indexes? If you run the queries with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on MySql console (for example `EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT confName, tableName FROM conferences WHERE enabled='1' ORDER BY id DESC`), does it show that it uses indexes?

---

I'm not sure that it's a real performance issue or not but the current `mysql_free_result` calls doesn't free all resources, just the last one because the code runs lots of queries in loops. You should put these calls immediately after the last use of the resource, for example:

```
while (...) {
    ...
    while($winner = mysql_fetch_array($catWinner)) {
        echo "<li>".$winner['place']. " ".$winner['name']."</li>";
    }
    // free $catWinner at the end of every iteration
    mysql_free_result($catWinner);
}
```

---

I don't think that (generally) a good design to create separate tables for (probably) the same type of records. Instead of creating separate tables for every conference, consider creating only one table. It should have a `conferenceId` attribute as well as the `conferences` table should have a `conferenceId` too (instead of the `tableName` attribute). (Don't forget the [foregin keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Example).)

If I'm right, this `conferenceId` could be in the `event` table and you don't need separate conference tables at all. (Feel free to post your database schema too. It could be worth a new question.)

---

Using `sprintf` does not make any sense here and in the similar calls:

```
$getExistingEvent = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT event FROM " . $conference['tableName']);
```

It's the same as

```
$getExistingEvent = "SELECT DISTINCT event FROM " . $conference['tableName'];
```

Or it could be

```
$getExistingEvent = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT event FROM %s", $conference['tableName']);
```

where `sprintf` does the including/formatting.

---

**Edit:**

I'd create the following indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `conferences` ADD INDEX `enabled`(`enabled`);
ALTER TABLE `2012rlc` ADD INDEX `event_id`(`event`);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Alrighty, I posted my database schema in the original post.  If I were to have all the data in one table, would organization be harder? Also, I have also put the output to the command you had me run in the original post as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it, please. The schema usally should be in 3NF which removes lots of redundancy. It makes modifications easier to do.